# Does IEnumerators require more resources than Arrays?

Tags: c#, arrays, mono, unity-game-engine, ienumerator

I have an implementation of the Sutherland–Hodgman algorithm, and so I need to return arrays frequently. I'm using Unity, so the answer needs to apply at least on the Mono runtime.

I'm wondering If it's best to return plain arrays, or if I could return as an IEnumerator, to reduce the time between garbage collections. So far I've been returning arrays, but I would really like to loose those calls to GC.Collect().

I guess the garbage collector would need to collect IEnumerators as well, and there is probably some overhead related as well?

Comment: I think you mean `IEnumerable`s (generic or otherwise). And mostly these are managed collections that yes, in general would have some memory overhead over arrays (and of course, will also need to be collected).

Comment: Where or why are you calling GC.Collect()? That is in general almost never advisable. If you run that Algorithm in your game loop, you should really *reuse* your collection, no matter if its an array or something else, otherwise the allocation / deallocation is likely to be a huge performance hog.

Comment: I really think I mean IEnumerator. Whatever it is, I did not mean some collection that implements IEnumerable, but a function that does several returns.

Comment: I'm not calling GC.Collect(), but it's called whenever the collector needs to. I don't have full control over when it's called.

Comment: Are you talking about Unity game engine or Unity IoC container?

Comment: It's the game engine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using generator co-routines (functions with many `yield return`s), no array is created or allocated. Everything is done in a streaming fashion. It is entirely possible to have infinite generators that work without getting an out of memory error:

```
public static IEnumerable<int> Odds(){
  for (int i = 1 ; ; i += 2)
    yield return i;
}
```

Therefore, if you frequently return big arrays only to be iterated and disposed immediately, the benefits will be huge, as the memory allocations will be much smaller. The garbage collector will be called less often and will have less work to do.

Comment: Thanks! This is what I'm investigating. Any idea about how much overhead is introduced?

Comment: What about cleaning up all the enumerator classes?

Comment: @Steinbitglis: theoretically, it does not introduce any more overhead than arrays. Instead of allocating and returning an array you allocate and return an IEnumerator. The overhead is comparable between the two, as the allocation happens only on the first yield return.

Comment: @MartinMulder: of course, you can write all of your code in one huge function in order to avoid all clean ups, but then what a mess would that be.

Answer (score 0):

First, just create your big array and keep it somewhere in memory. The rest of the application can retrieve a reference to that array and itterate through it.

The best way and fastest to itterate through an array is using `for`.

If you are using `foreach`, evertime (under water) a enumerator class is create, which will need to be cleaned up after it has done its duty.